# Type Error: Cannot Read Property "x" from undefined. Only when I include an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script

I am trying to loop through values from a google sheet column that first runs through a function to parse a response on a json page to get a unique identifier, then another json response using the unique identifier to find an attribute's value (true or false).

I have tried a "for loop" that I will include in my code

```
function main(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Pat ID');
  var zdPatIDs = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();

  for (id in zdPatIDs){
    var ptArray = getZDUser(zdPatIDs[id])
    // var updateProfile = coldChainOffered(ptArray)
    var response = getResponse(ptArray.name);
  }
}

// returns requestor ID from value of patients in google sheet
function getZDUser(zdPatIDs){
  var url = 'https://someURL.com/api/v2/search.json?query='+zdPatIDs
  var options =
   {
     "method": "get",
     "contentType" : "application/json",
     "headers": 
     {
         "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("bearer/token:string of numbers")
     },
     "muteHttpExceptions": true
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  var response = JSON.parse(response)
  return response.results[0].requester_id
}

// returns json cold chain offered response from requester id function
function getResponse(ptArray){
  var url = 'https://someURL.com/api/v2/users/' + ptArray + '.json'
  var options =
    {
      "method": "get",
      "contentType" : "application/json",
      "headers": 
      {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("bearer/token:string 
   of numbers")
      },
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  var response = JSON.parse(response)
  return response.user.user_fields.cold_chain_offered
}
```

When I only have one value and no for loop the correct response is returned, however when there are multiple I get the type error thrown

Comment: I get the errors with the returns of the functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot going on, and not all of it is supplied. Including a minimal example of your JSON would be good to help us figure out what's going on, but I'll see if I can cover some other issues I see.

First off, re-declaring `response` may be part of the issue. It's not good programming practice to re-declare variables and it'll even fail your program in other languages. You are doing this at least 2x in your example, so please fix that.

Next, you should generally `null` check your objects before trying to use them. If your response is an empty string, empty JSON, or simply doesn't have that key, you'll get an error. Including the error(s) in your Question will also help us figure out what problem(s) you're having.

Also, formatting your code to have less on each line will help you figure out what parameters you are sending and if they have any errors that are causing you to not get the data you expect. (I'll edit the Question here is a sec to show you what I mean.) Using a [coding standard](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp) might be useful, especially if you are coding professionally or have peers/partners that will look at your code.

Using [Fiddler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_(software)), or something similar will help you figure out what exactly you are getting for returned data, so you can try to figure out what's "not right" with your code.

And lastly, looking at the `JSON.parse` documentation might help you figure out if the JSON you are getting is correctly formatted and if it has anything else that doesn't conform to the expected standards. If you are writing the server side of things, the difference between using a `'` and `"` is crucial in JSON, as I've found out the hard way.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: I am a self taught coder who learned from other peoples code at my work who don't follow guidelines or write comments lol. It ended up being a super simple fix where I needed to encode the user type into a URI Component then pass that ti the url as well as add a break in my main function! Thank you for your input and I will definitely try to follow some sort of structure @computercarguy

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. I am a mix of self taught and school taught, although even when I was in school for programming, I still taught myself probably 90% of what I learned. I've over 25 years of learning programming and now have about 7 years professional experience in it, so I know how hard it can be to learn Standards. Believe me, it helps. Maybe not at first, but it will.